# Run memtest on EFI CentOS7

Tags: centos, memory, hardware, uefi

I am trying to hunt down a potential hardware issue with my server. After I installed `memtest86+.x86_64`, I ran `memtest-setup`, which told me

> memtest86+ does not support EFI platforms

Now I am facing the question how to run memtest?

Answer (score 1):

[ALT Rescue](http://en.altlinux.org/rescue) got [EFI Memtest86 by PassMark](http://www.memtest86.com/) :)
It's proprietary now unfortunately but I've asked to redistribute it as there was (and is) no free alternative back then and it seems at the moment either...